# findItemsAdvanced in eBay Finding API not using applied itemFilters

Tags: xml, ebay-api

When I use `findItemsAdvanced` request in eBay Finding API to search for items by a particular user and giving `itemfilters` as `MaxPrice` and `MinPrice` the output result doesn't filter according to the price range provided in filter...

I am using the below request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<findItemsAdvancedRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<itemFilter>
<name>MinPrice</name>
<value>100.00</value>
<name>ListingType</name>
<value>FixedPrice</value>
<name>MaxPrice</name>
<value>200.00</value>
<name>Seller</name>
<value>anysellerID</value>
</itemFilter>
<sortOrder>PricePlusShippingLowest</sortOrder>
<paginationInput>
<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
<entriesPerPage>10</entriesPerPage>
</paginationInput>
</findItemsAdvancedRequest>

The output request doesn't filter by the MaxPrice and MinPrice filter value and return all the items by the particular user.
```

---

I have found the answer I had to use `ItemFilter` tag separately for each filter as shown below

```
<itemFilter>
<name>MinPrice</name>
<value>100.00</value>
</itemFilter>
<itemFilter>
<name>MaxPrice</name>
<value>500.00</value>
</itemFilter>
<itemFilter>
```

Comment: You should put your solution into an actual answer and mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer I had to use ItemFilter tag separately for each filter as shown below`

```
<itemFilter>
<name>MinPrice</name>
<value>100.00</value>
</itemFilter>
<itemFilter>
<name>MaxPrice</name>
<value>500.00</value>
</itemFilter>
<itemFilter>
```